# Which typescript version is my Visual Studio using?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.4

Rather than guessing what I'm running based on versions I've installed or what the grammar looks like it understands, is there a place in the sln, csproj, or other place that I can I look at to definitively see (and configure) which version of typescript I'm using?

As background informatino, I'm on VS2013 Update 2, and I just downloaded and ran the tsc 1.4 compiler extension. [1]

My pre-existing tsc 1.0 project appears to still be using the tsc 1.0 grammar to parse ts files, but I don't know which compiler it's using.

[1] https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2d42d8dc-e085-45eb-a30b-3f7d50d55304

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The csproj file can have a `<TypescriptToolsVersion>` property. You can add it if it's not there. If you create a new Typescript project from the project template, you should see it. For example:

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.4</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

This property is used by the imported Microsoft.TypeScript.targets file. You might want to verify that file is being loaded from the location you expect. It should be something like C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript

Comment: <TypescriptToolsVersion> didn't exist in my project. Thanks.